# Why does Apple Sign In on iOS prompt for your name and email upon every authentication?

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

I need to implement Apple Sign In for the web and iOS.

I am requesting the `name` and `email` scopes. I expect the user be prompted for this information **the first time** they sign in to my app.

- On the web, it works as expected: the first time a user attempts to authenticate, they are presented with the option to specify a name and email (or to use the relay proxy). After that, the fact that they've authenticated with my application is stored in their AppleID account, and subsequent authentications do not prompt them to specify a name and email address. They can forget my app by going to https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage, but otherwise they are not prompted to enter their name and email upon authentication.
- On iOS, I am getting prompted for a name/email every time I authenticate. It treats every authentication like the first time I've authenticated. Is there something I need to do for it to remember that the user has already authenticated with my app? **I don't want to ask users their name/email every time they log in, only the first time.**

I looked at the documentation and [this example app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple?language=objc), and that just seems to be how it works on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior you can expect when using the Simulator. On a real device, you are, indeed, prompted for the name/email only the first time.

Comment: similar to these I can receive email id and name every time I sign in into my app. But according to apple guidelines it is send only once. Is it because am using simulator ?